# an efficient way to detect when the system's hour changed from xx:59 to xy:00

Tags: c, time, posix

I have an application on Linux that needs to change some parameters each hour, e.g. at 11:00, 12:00, etc. and the system's date can be changed by the user anytime.

Is there any signal, posix function that would provides me when a hour changes from xx:59 to xx+1:00?

Normally, I use `localtime(3)` to fetch the current time each seconds then compare if the minute part is equal to `0`. however, it does not look a good way to do it, in order to detect a change, I need to call the same function each second for an hour. Especially I run the code on an embedded board that would be good to use less resources.

Here is an example code how I do it:

```
static char *fetch_time() { // I use this fcn for some other purpose to fetch the time info
    char *p;
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[13];
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    strftime (buffer,13,"%04Y%02m%02d%02k%02M",timeinfo);
    p = (char *)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
    strcpy(p, buffer);
    return p;
}


static int hour_change_check(){
    char *p;
    p = fetch_time();
    char current_minute[3] = {'\0'};
    current_minute[0] = p[10];
    current_minute[1] = p[11];
    int current_minute_as_int = atoi(current_minute);
    if (current_minute_as_int == 0){
        printf("current_min: %d\n",current_minute_as_int);
        free(p);
        return 1;
    }
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    while(1){
    int x = hour_change_check();
    printf("x:%d\n",x);
    sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such signal, but traditionally the method of waiting until some target time is to compute how long it is between "now" and "then", and then call `sleep()`:

```
now = time(NULL);
when = (some calculation);
if (when > now)
    sleep(when - now);
```

If you need to be very precise about the transition from, e.g., 3:59:59 to 4:00:00, you may want to sleep for a slightly shorter time in case of time adjustments due to leap seconds.  (If you are running in a portable device in which time zones can change, you also need to worry about picking up the new location, and if it runs on a half-hour offset, redo all computations.  There's even Solar Time in Saudi Arabia....)

Edit: per the suggestion from R.., if `clock_nanosleep()` is available, calculate a `timespec` value for the absolute wakeup time and call it with the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_nanosleep.html for the definition for `clock_nanosleep()`.  However, if time is allowed to step backwards (e.g., localtime with zone shifts), you may still have to do some maintenance checking.

Comment: You could setup a signal to do it with `setitimer` or POSIX `timer_create` and `timer_settime`, but generally the signal approach is much uglier and more error-prone.

Comment: I thought it, the issue may arise here that  let's say the function calculates how long to sleep at `12:25` and and set function to sleep 34 min 58 sec. And, at `12:26`, the user set the time to `12:59:56`... I don't need very precise time change information, it could be even couple seconds delay

Comment: Perhaps use `clock_nanosleep` with the `TIMER_ABSTIME` flag to wake up at a particular time (or later) rather than after a fixed duration.

Comment: @R.: yes, that's a way to go if you need multiple different events and have other work to do.  (And `setitimer` is particularly useful for repeating events.)  As for `clock_nanosleep`, it's not portable, but it sounds like a good option.

Comment: @angs: yes, a large clock skew is a real problem (which is why `ntp` normally won't do that).  A typical workaround for that is to wake up once every "some interval", i.e., set the sleep argument to no more than some maximum.

Comment: `clock_nanosleep` is in POSIX 2008 base, so formally, it's portable. If there are some implementations lagging behind modern standards, that's another issue. OP said Linux so presumably this is no problem.

Comment: @R..: Yes, it's just not available on all the systems *I* have at hand. :-)

Comment: Also, note that the system clock does not keep local time, so changes from daylight time or time zones will not mess up the clock, but they do need to be factored into the wakeup time. One could compute `localtime` one hour into the future and make sure there are no odd jumps, and in case there is one, binary-search the interval to find where it takes place and plan to wake up at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually measured the overhead used in your solution of polling the time once per second (or even two given some of your other comments)?

The number of instructions that are invoked is minimal AND you do not have any looping.  So at worse maybe the cpu uses 100 micro-seconds (0.1 ms, or 0.0001 s) time.  This estimate is very dependent on the processor used in your embedded system and its clock speed, but the idea is that **maybe** the polling logic uses 1/1000 of the total time available.

Also, you could optimize your `hour_change_check` code to do all of the time calcs and not call another function that issues `malloc` which has to be immediately freed!  Also, if this is an embedded *nix system, can you still run this polling logic in its own thread so that when it issues `sleep()` it will not interfere or delay other units of work.

Hence, measure the problem and see if it is a significant problem.  The polling's performance must be balanced against the requirement that when a user changes the time then the hour change MUST be detected.  That is, I think polling every second will catch the hour rollover even if the user changes the time, but is the overhead worth it.  Well, how much, exactly, overhead is there?